# Create hyperlinks in XLSXWriter using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create hyperlinks in an dataset that is eventually exported using xlswriter using a function I create in my python script. However, the output produced is not as expected.

`=HYPERLINK()` in Excel takes two arguments. These are the destination URL and the anchor text. It is this that I am trying to produce in Python using XLSXWriter so that when imported, Excel is able to read column as a link.

See exmaple below.

```
#create exmaple df
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.twitter.com','https://www.reddit.com']})

#create function
def make_hyperlink(x):
for urls in df['urls']:
    return '=HYPERLINK(' + urls, "Site Link"

#apply function
df['hyperlink'] = df['urls'].apply(lambda x: make_hyperlink(x))

#view df 
df
```

output:

```
    urls    hyperlink
0   https://www.google.com  (=HYPERLINK(https://www.google.com, Site Link)
1   https://www.youtube.com (=HYPERLINK(https://www.google.com, Site Link)
2   https://www.twitter.com (=HYPERLINK(https://www.google.com, Site Link)
3   https://www.reddit.com  (=HYPERLINK(https://www.google.com, Site Link)
```

I am expecting the output to display each of the individual URLs with 'Site Link' as the anchor text so I am unsure as to why the function only applies to the first URL but four times.

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your `make_hyperlink()` function and how you apply it. Here is a corrected version:

```py
import pandas as pd

#create exmaple df
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.youtube.com',
                            'https://www.twitter.com','https://www.reddit.com']})

#create function
def make_hyperlink(url):
    return '=HYPERLINK("%s", "Site Link")' % url


#apply function
df['hyperlink'] = df['urls'].apply(make_hyperlink)

#view df
print(df)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]